# How to properly handle axios errors and how to get detailed error descriptions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a question about axios and error handling. So this is the method I'm using to handle errors when the user logins from the front end:

```
    axios.post('http://localhost:3001/login',
        {
            login: user.login,
            password: user.password,
        }
    )
    .then(
        (response) => {
            // code
        },
        (error) => {
            // error handling
        }
    );
```

This is the second method:

```
    axios.post('http://localhost:3001/login',
        {
            login: user.login,
            password: user.password,
        }
    )
    .then(
        (response) => {
            // code
        }
    ).catch((error) => {
        // error handling
    });
```

What is the best approach? Is it the same? When the server is unreachable the error message is the same: "Network Error". Is there any way to get a more detailed error? (For example in the console I get a CORS error)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error can occur at different parts - Request, Response.

Request errors occur when there is no response. Like 404 etc, which has no default response.

Response errors have when API sends custom response to handle errors.

I used to handle this way:

```
const handleErrorResponse = (error) => {
  let errorResponse;
  if(error.response && error.response.data) {
    // I expect the API to handle error responses in valid format
    errorResponse = error.response.data;
    // JSON stringify if you need the json and use it later
  } else if(error.request) {
    // TO Handle the default error response for Network failure or 404 etc.,
    errorResponse = error.request.message || error.request.statusText;
  } else {
    errorResponse = error.message;
  }
  throw new Error(errorResponse);
}
```

now,

```
axios.get(/foo/bar)
.then(res => doSOmething())
.catch(err => handleErrorResponse(err))
```

The I use error handling the error response as string. 
The same you can use it with axios interceptor should you need.

Answer (score -2):

This is not valid, `then` accepts single argument

```
.then(
        (response) => {
            // code
        },
        (error) => {
            // error handling
        }
    );
```

Only this's valid

```
.then(
        (response) => {
            // code
        }
    ).catch((error) => {
        // error handling
    });
```

Comment: Not so. Its shorthand for both response and error. Both way works